# How to select a set of parent objects who have children contained in this set of children?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following setup:

```
@trials = Trial.includes(:lawyers)
lawyers = Lawyer.where(:trial_id => @trials.pluck(:id)).near(lat_lon_coordinates, 5000)

close_trials = lawyers.map { |law| law.trial }.uniq

class Trial < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lawyers
end

class Lawyer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :trial
end
```

I am trying to select all lawyers that belong to a specific trial if they are within a specified radial distance of a latitude and longitude (lat_lon_coordinates).  Currently, *close_trials = lawyers.map { |law| law.trial }.uniq* takes about 0.01 seconds to run (since each lawyer can belong to more than one trial and there are hundreds to thousands of lawyers).  Is there a way to speed up the *close_trials* query?  Or more generally, is there another solution I'm thinking of that would yield a more performant solution?